# jquery stack overflow with simple slider

Tags: javascript, jquery

Unsatisfied with existing sliders (mostly because they're bloated code and require external script calls), I decided to try to write a simple, site-specific inline slider script. However, I get a stack overflow error.

```
        <div id="featured">
        <div class="tween">
            <div class="cropimg">
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                text
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tween">
            <div class="cropimg">
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                text
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tween">
            <div class="cropimg">
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                text
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        <script>
        var _rys = jQuery.noConflict();

        _rys("document").ready(function(){
            var timeOut = 5000;
            setTimeout(nextSlide(1),timeOut);
        });

        function nextSlide(next) {
            var i = 1;
            var numberOfChildren = _rys("#featured").children().length;

            _rys(".tween:nth-child("+next+")").fadeTo(500,1);
            while (i<=numberOfChildren) {
                // loop through the children and make those that are opaque invisible
                if (i != next) {
                    if (_rys(".tween:nth-child("+i+")").css('opacity') != 0) {
                        _rys(".tween:nth-child("+i+")").css('opacity',0);
                    }
                }
                i++;
            }

            if (next>=numberOfChildren) {
                setTimeout(nextSlide(1), 5000);
            } else {
                setTimeout(nextSlide(next+1), 5000);
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: This should be `setTimeout(function(){nextSlide(1)},timeOut);` and so on for each of your setTimeout() call. Using `setTimeout(nextSlide(1),timeOut);`, you are calling recursively `nextSlide()` method without putting it in event queue (no delay) but putting returned value (here undefined). FYI, your `while` loop is really not the best which can be done

Comment: @UmairShahYousafzai When you're asking a question on SO without having searched by yourself before :)

Comment: `_rys(".tween:not(:nth-child("+i+"))").css('opacity',0);` would be enough, without any `while` loop

Comment: that's it, A. Wolff!

Comment: @tektiv : Ahaa...My Bad...Just Googled And I was surprised to see that it was too much basic question..! :D